# How to display an index in a array with a function

Tags: c

I am trying to display the lowest price index in the array that is found through my function. But I am struggling to figure out how to make it display the specific index. Where do I need to pass the index variable in order to make display the lowest index with my display function?

```
#define COLOR_SIZE 50
#define PLANT_ARRAY_SIZE 3

struct Plant
{
    int plantID;
    double price;
    char color[COLOR_SIZE];
};

int main()
{
int index;

//create array
struct Plant totalPlants[PLANT_ARRAY_SIZE];

//initialize array
for (int count = 0; count < PLANT_ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    {
        initializePlant(totalPlants);
    }

// find lowest
index = findCheapestPlant(totalPlants, PLANT_ARRAY_SIZE);

//display lowest cost plant     
displayPlant(totalPlants[index]);

return 0;
}

void initializePlant(struct Plant *x)
{
    printf("\nEnter the information for the next plant\n");

    printf("Enter plant ID as an integer>");

    scanf("%d", &(x->plantID));
    printf("Enter the plant price as a double>");

    scanf("%lf", &(x->price));

    printf("Enter the perdominant color of the plant>");

    scanf("%s", &(x->color));

void displayPlant(struct Plant *x)
{

    printf("\nThe cheapest plant is to be...\n");
    printf("Plant ID %d which costs $%.2lf and the color is %s\n", x->plantID, x->price, x->color);
}

int findCheapestPlant(struct Plant x[], int length)
{
    double lowest;
    int index = -1;
    int i = 0;

    if (length > 0)
    {
        lowest = x[i].price;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i].price < lowest)
        {
            index = i;
            lowest = x[i].price;
        }



    }

    return index;
}

}
```

I expect the display function to output the lowest price plant but i get errors.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `findCheapestPlant()`?

Comment: Yeah sure just did it.

Comment: Please also post your errors or include the the code for your initialization function `initializePlant`

Comment: I think your problem is you're expecting a pointer in `displayPlant` but you are passing in a variable

Comment: Also added the initialization function

Comment: No that's not it I ordered them correctly and still didn't work. My problem is that I don't understand how to incorporate the returned index value from my cheapest function with my display function.

Comment: You're not calling initializePlant correctly. You should be using the count variable in the call, like `initializePlant(&totalPlants[count]);`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors addressed in the comments, in addition to fixing these errors, the following should help you achieve what you want to do.

To get the code to display the index as well, maybe change the declaration of `displayPlant` to take the index as well:

`displayPlant(struct Plant *x, int index)`

and then pass the index you have in your main to the function like so

`displayPlant(totalPlants[index], index);`

Then of course you should alter your printf statement to something like:

`printf("Plant ID %d (index: %d) which costs $%.2lf and the color is %s\n", x->plantID, index, x->price, x->color);`

> EDIT: I should also say that initializing your index to `-1` is a bad idea, because it will result in seg faults unless your code includes checks for the index being >= 0.

Additionally add this `index = i;` or `index = 0` here in your code:

```
if (length > 0)
{
    lowest = x[i].price;
    index = i; //here
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. This is something that I also tried to do but I was trying to maintain keeping the display function with only 1 parameter which is my biggest issue. If I can not figure out a solution to maintaining a single parameter I will definitely change it.

Comment: There are different ways to only use one parameter. You could make a struct that contains both the index and the array (pointer) and pass that. You could also make one of the variables global. However, I really think two parameters is probably best.